# using wordpress category plugin - how do i list in order=desc?

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I'm using this plugin

http://watershedstudio.com/portfolio/software-development/wordpress-category-posts-plugin/

that uses this php

works just fine but it lists the category posts alphabetically - how can i list them so that the newest ones are listed first?

Comment: Make sure you surround your '<?php' and '?>' in your question with the code markup so it appears in the question.

Comment: @Michael: why? it is a just like 3,00+ other wordpress questions here.

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin change line 13 to

```
    $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $catID, 'numberposts' => -1, 'order' => ASC, 'orderby' => date));
```

I just changed title to date.